# relation between eccentricity and weiner index

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I was going through a topic $Weiner$ $Index$. Is there any relation between eccentricity of the graph and the Weiner Index of the graph.

Any hint or link will be appreciated.
thanks a lot.

**NOTE**: ***Weiner index*** is defined as the sum of all distance between unordered pairs of vertices.